# Problem with set ordering property In UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, indexpath

I have a strange problem with `collectionView`, I have two prototypes, first one should draw in `indexPath.row=0` and the second one should be created four times. 
The second prototype contains one UIView for holding an icon that created with paintCode app, and a text label. I have also four icons for each cell.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
switch indexPath.row {
case 0:
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as? ViewData {
        return cell
    }
case 1,2,3,4:
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as? ViewData {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 1:
            cell.dataIcon.is1stIcon = true
            cell.title.text = "1"
        case 2:
            cell.dataIcon.is2ndIcon = true
            cell.title.text = "2"
        case 3:
            cell.dataIcon.is3rdIcon = true
            cell.title.text = "3"
        case 4:
            cell.dataIcon.is4thIcon = true
            cell.title.text = "4"
        default:
            break
        }

        return cell
    }
default:
    break
}
return UICollectionViewCell()
```

}

The problem is, all text is located in the right place (row), but the `1stIcon` in the `indexPath.row=1` will be shown in `indexPath.row=3`, and `3rtIcon` will be shown in `indexPath.row=1`.
First I thought maybe the problem come from the icons, but whatever I put in these row, has the same wrong tendency. 
What do you thing about it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happens as of cell dequeuing you need to re-set everything before using it like

```
  cell.reset()
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 1:
        cell.dataIcon.is1stIcon = true
        cell.title.text = "1"
    case 2:
        cell.dataIcon.is2ndIcon = true
        cell.title.text = "2"
    case 3:
        cell.dataIcon.is3rdIcon = true
        cell.title.text = "3"
    case 4:
        cell.dataIcon.is4thIcon = true
        cell.title.text = "4"
    default:
        break
  }
```

---

```
func reset() {
  // show all of them
  self.dataIcon.is1ndIcon = false
  self.dataIcon.is2ndIcon = false
  self.dataIcon.is3ndIcon = false
  self.dataIcon.is4ndIcon = false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but where I should write these two codes, the first one I supposed i should write in cellForItemAt, but  reset()? in viewdidload?

Comment: `cell.reset` directly above `switch` and implement the function inside the cell class

Answer (score 0):

I think you should work on [collectionViewLayout] delegation method.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // Specify the cell frame of row=1
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width - 20, height: collectionView.bounds.height/4-5)
    }

    // Other...
    return CGSize(width: (collectionView.bounds.width-40)/3 - 1, height: collectionView.bounds.width/3-5)
```

}